# Show the default value for a variable

Tags: mysql, variables, default-value, mysql-variables

I am using `SET GLOBAL <variable> = <value>` to modify dynamic settings in mysql and I am wondering if there is some way to get the default value for each variable? For instance, if I use the following:

```
SET GLOBAL max_connections = 1000;
```

and then list the variable using:

```
SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'max_connections';
```

I can see the modified value `1000`, but is there possible to get the default value for this system variable without checking the configuration files?

I am using mysql 5.7 on ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: I believe it is `151` for max_connections.
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_connections

Comment: This was just an example and does not answer the question :)

Comment: I think you have to look at official documentation for the variables, one you have overwritten them with custom values.

Comment: I know I can check the documentation, the question is if and how I can do this without reading the documentation for each variable :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[From the manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/set-variable.html#set-variable-system-variables):

> To set a global system variable value to the compiled-in MySQL default
>   value [...] set the variable to the value `DEFAULT`.

That means you can do this:

```
SET @@GLOBAL.max_connections = 1234;

/*
 * Proceed in this order
 * 1) Backup current value
 * 2) Reset to default
 * 3) Read the current value
 * 4) Restore the backup value if necesssary
 */

SET @oldvalue = @@GLOBAL.max_connections;
SET @@GLOBAL.max_connections = DEFAULT;
SET @defvalue = @@GLOBAL.max_connections;
SET @@GLOBAL.max_connections = @oldvalue;

SELECT @@GLOBAL.max_connections AS `current value`
     , @defvalue AS `default value`
-- 1234 and 151
```

The `@oldvalue` and `@defvalue` are user variables.

Answer (score 3):

In MySQL 5.7 you can use `performance_schema` to get the variables.

Before modifying or `set` you can select the variable to see the default value then modify.

**Method #1**

```
SELECT 
    VARIABLE_VALUE
FROM
    performance_schema.global_variables
WHERE
    VARIABLE_NAME = 'max_connections';
```

**Output #1**

> ```
> | VARIABLE_VALUE |
> | :------------- |
> | 151            |
> ```

**Method #2**

If you are not sure the exact name of variable use `like`, it can used used also in above query too.

```
SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'max_connect%';
```

**Output #2**

> ```
> Variable_name      | Value
> :----------------- | :----
> max_connect_errors | 100  
> max_connections    | 151
> ```

**Method #3**

```
SELECT @@GLOBAL.max_connections;
```

**Output #3**

> ```
> | @@GLOBAL.max_connections |
> | -----------------------: |
> |                      151 |
> ```

Refer here [db-fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=495fdcfc55b081782567003a11d287d8)

**Note:**
If you need to have a history kind of thing then you need to create a table to store those values before changing.

**P.S.** There is one more type of variables `session`. By replacing `global` to `session` those variables can be changed but it will affect only to the current session.

**credits:** @scaisedge, @richard

Comment: This seems to be a good solution. I will try this as soon as possible and see if it works as expected.

Answer (score 2):

Could be selecting from information_schema.GLOBAL_STATUS

```
select VARIABLE_VALUE 
from information_schema.GLOBAL_STATUS 
where VARIABLE_NAME = 'max_connections';
```

Comment: Hm, the table does not contain any variable named `max_connections`? Looking on the `global_variables` table it contains the variable, but with the changed value. Any thoughts on how to solve this?

Comment: I am runng mysql 5.7

Comment: the default value is  151  as in doc https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_connections

Comment: Yes I know I can check the documentation to get this information, but you don't have any thoughts on how to do this by actually querying the database?

Comment: In my.ini is not present  .. so this param setting  is only in DB

Answer (score 2):

This might not be ideal but if it were me trying to solve the problem I'd create my own table with all of the initial values and reference that when I needed.

```
CREATE TABLE 
   default_variables
SELECT 
   * 
FROM 
   information_schema.GLOBAL_STATUS;
```

This would require you to spin up a new DB installation that is the same version as the one you're currently using, but I think you could use this method to solve your problem.

Simply export the data and import it wherever you need it.

I don't currently see any built-in way to query the defaults.

Comment: This is a good idea to keep track of the default values, but in this case I don't really have any possibility to create any tables since I don't have write access to the database.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using this

```
mysqld --verbose --help
```

based on https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html it will display compiled-in default.

To see specific variable you may use grep:

```
mysqld --verbose --help | grep -i 'max-connections'
```

Comment: Yes this works, but I am not able to execute any binaries or read any configuration files. The solution must be by querying the database for the information if possible.

Answer (score 0):

*[Edit: Extends [elomat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12077069/elomat)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58502050/2800418); I have not enough reputation to comment in it]*

All mysql* commands have the `--no-defaults` option for *not reading* configuration files, so you could use:

```
mysqld --no-defaults --verbose --help | awk '/Variables/,/^$/' | less
```

As you cannot execute commands I suggest **running this command in a virtual machine created with the same distro/distro version/MySQL version** (To find MySQL's version use the query `select version();`).

On the other hand, if it is a locally compiled binary maybe you could copy the executable to another machine with compatible runtime libraries and without execution restrictions.

Notes: The `awk` patterns filter out the starting options until the word *Variable* is found, and then keeps printing text until an empty line or end of text is reached. This instance of `mysqld` does not keep running as it hasn't the `--daemonize` option.